# JQuery Mobile -Text input does not apply styles

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I am trying to show a text in the textbox in a Mobile App using JQuery Mobile. Somehow i get the textbox getting displayed like that in desktop. Styles are not getting applied to the textbox.

If i see in Firebug , i see that i get an empty `class` with no style in it. This style must be applied- `class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"`

But it isn't. Any idea if i am missing something to apply some js stuff before?

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MobileLayout.cshtml";
}

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<form action="~/Mobile/Register/Complete" method="post" data-ajax="false" id="formId">    
<div id="container" style="margin: -6px;">   
   <div>
   <h1 style="margin: 0 0 5px;">Register</h1>
    <div class="section">
        <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0;">Enter the fields</h3>
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <label for="UserName">Username</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new {@class = "ui-field-contain", style = "width:100%", @readonly = true})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>
     </div>    
    </div>
  <div>    
</form>
```

Many Thanks In Advance,

Thanks,

Kan

Comment: All you code here shows is you are adding a class `ui-field-contain` to the textbox (which is repeated in the enclosing `div`). Do you  mean `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"})`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke- Thanks for the quick response. I was expecting that, but it doesn't do that..
I tried this too, but this doesn't apply the style to the div

 <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="UserName">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" value="@Model.Username" readonly="true" />
            </div>

Comment: What do you mean _but this doesn't apply the style to the div_? Are you trying to apply those classes to a `div` or to the textbox?

Comment: i have to apply the classes to the textbox

Comment: Which the code in my first comment will do (inspect the html that it generates). If its not appearing as you believe it should, check that the style sheet containing those definitions is being loaded correctly

Comment: I realize now you may be getting confused and I suspect you do actually need to apply the styles to the enclosing div. [Go to this page](http://api.jquerymobile.com/textinput/), right click on one of the textboxes and Inspect Element to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to remove these below classes in my JavaScript code:

```
this.page.find('.ui-shadow-inset').removeClass('ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset');
```

when i removed the above code, it started working and the styles are getting applied.

Thanks All for the responses